# C++ and QT docker image for CI

Tags: visual-studio, continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment

I'm new to CI/CD and I'm trying to figure out how can I create my own Docker image with VS2015 / VS2017 and QT, then put this Docker in my own Linux hosted Gitlab EE, so my C++ QT project would have working runner to be used in CI/CD. Is it even possible? Please advise